# Flask-Restplus marshall with a field that is a class method

Tags: python, flask, flask-restplus

I'm wondering if it is possible to marshall a resource with a field that is not a part of the model, meaning, it returns data from a method within the model class.

For instance, let's assume this is the model object I want to marshall (it's a simpliefied version of the actual model)

```
class Program(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    location = Column(String)

    def get_students(self, **kw):
        return self._union('students', **kw)
```

The get_students method what it does is join several list of students from other programs.

So, in my view I have this:

```
@ns.route('/<string:id>')
@api.response(404, 'Program not found.')
class ProgramItem(Resource):

    @api.marshal_with(program_with_students)
    def get(self, id):
        """
        Returns a program with a list of students.
        """
        program = Program.query.filter(Program.id == id).one()
        return program
```

And this is the serializer:

```
program_with_students = api.model('Program with students', {
    'id': fields.String(required=True, description='Program identifier'),
    'name': fields.String(required=True, description='Program name'),
    'location': fields.String(required=True, attribute='location_name', description='Program location'),
})
```

So, my question is, how do I marshall a field I want to call students and that returns what the method get_students returns?

Been reading flask-restplus, and I'm not really sure the [field.Raw](https://flask-restplus.readthedocs.io/en/stable/marshalling.html#custom-fields-multiple-values) is exactly what I should use...basically, I'm not sure I can reference the Program object in the [format](https://flask-restplus.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/flask_restplus/fields.html#Raw.format) method...seems restplus is passing just the value but not a reference to the main object?

**EDIT: Found the solution...**

Just using attribute and calling a lambda would make it...so simple :D

```
  'students': fields.List(fields.Nested(program_student), required=True, description='List of students on program',
                        attribute=lambda obj: obj.get_students())
```

FYI, program_student is just another serializer, since Student is also a model, but that's irrelevent right now

Comment: Made an edit to answer myself :D

Comment: You can actually answer to your own question and mark it as the answer. Might make this question better referenced.